# Android : Why is enable bluetooth discovery activity not returning to onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

I am firing an activity to enable bluetooth discovery. I have a callback `onActivityResult` but it is not being called regardless of me pressing 'Deny' or 'Allow' when the popup comes.

I only have one main activity and the intent is fired when user presses a button.

here is my code:

```
    // button press calls this

public void onStart(View v)
{
    if (bButtonStartPressed)
    {                   
        Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);

        startActivityForResult(intent, DISCOVERY_REQUEST);      

        changeViewState((Button)v, R.drawable.btn_on);          

    }
  ... other stuff...
  }
```

and here is the onActivityResult:

```
/*
 * Activity Result
 */
//@Override
protected void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d("OnActivity", "Result : " + requestCode + " " + resultCode);

    if (requestCode == ENABLE_BLUETOOTH)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            ...do something...  
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == DISCOVERY_REQUEST)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            ...do something...  
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            changeViewState((Button)btnStart, R.drawable.btn_normal);
        }
    }       
}
```

One thing you will notice is that the @Override is commented out and it is because when I override the onActivityResult method i get this error:

```
The method OnActivityResult(int, int, Intent) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am blind!

the 'o' should be lower case in `OnActivityResult()` above.